# Как перенести кнопки в QdateTimeEdit

Tags: qt

Как можно перенести кнопки как показал на рисунки с помощью stylesheet ? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пили свой виджет, бро

Comment: ...или читайте документацию ;)

Answer (score 2):

кое-что можно конечно сделать...

```
QDateTimeEdit {
    /* резервируем место под кнопки */
     padding-top: 20px; 
     padding-bottom: 20px; 
     border: none;
    /* это чтобы белый бэк был только у строки ввода*/
    background-color: white;
     background-clip: content;
 }
/* переопледеляем сабконтролы (кнопки "туды"/"сюды" )*/
 QDateTimeEdit::up-button {
     /* переносим кнопку в марджин */
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
     /* определяем расположение */
     subcontrol-position: top center;
     /* и размер кнопки */
     width: 16px;
     height:16px;
 }

 QDateTimeEdit::down-button {
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
     subcontrol-position: bottom center;
      width: 16px;
      height:16px;
 }
```

получается такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это ещё от стиля зависит, в смысле, что разрешено менять. Я бы на Fusion перешёл. Или Cleanlooks  если Qt4

Comment: @Pavel Gridin есть какие программы для редактирования виджетов в qt? Ну там отредактировал а потом добавил код в stylesheet.